# Windows phone app webview doesn't retain latex output

Tags: c#, webview, windows-phone-8.1

I am in a strange problem. I want to display some text as beautified mathematical expression using Latex in my Webview but on running the app on phone/simulator it blinks the expected output for a second and then flattens it as a normal string.

Html content I am Navigating the Webview to:

```
string htmlFragment = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>" +
              "  <script src=\"http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=AM_HTMLorMML\"></script>  "+                 
              "  </head><font size=30>  <body> `((n(n+1))/2)^2`  </body> </html>   ";
```

Retrieving the content from Webview after rendering HTML gives me an empty html page with lot of tags from MathMl but no content to display.

Why the rendered page persist and why the html content comes out as empty ?

Can someone suggest me something ?

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the Windows phone pretends it is Safari, MathJax is getting confused about what browser it is running in.  See [this bug report](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1085) for details.  A fix will be included in the next release of MathJax.

You might try using the SVG output rather than the HTML-CSS output, as that is not browser-dependent.  There is no combined configuration file for that, however, so you would need to include your own configuration in-line.

Comment: thanks for this very precise answer. May be I should wait for new release.